# Kafka Streams - what is stored in memory and disk in Streams App

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am new to Kafka Streams and I've been reading [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/documentation/streams/developer-guide) on how to setup Kafka Streams application.

I am not clear though, how the data is handled - what is stored in memory and what is stored on disk. I have seen RocksDB mentioned somewhere, but not in the streams documentation.

The problem I am trying to solve is as follows. I have 2 Kafka topics, both key-value store type that keep the oldest value for each key. In my streams application I want to join both topics and output the join back to kafka that can be later consumed by some sink. What I am worried about is that it is not clear how joins are performed. Both topics will have GBs of data, so there is no chance that is going to fit in Streams App memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read each topic as a `KTable` and do a table-table join:

```java
KTable table1 = builder.table("topic-1");
KTable table2 = builder.table("topic-2");

KTable joinResult = table1.join(table2, ...);
joinResult.to("output-topic");
```

For more details see:
http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#ktable-ktable-join
Also check out the examples: https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/tree/3.3.0-post/kafka-streams

For runtime, both topics will be materialized in a RocksDB state store. RocksDB is able to spill to disk. Also note, that a single RocksDB instance only needs to hold the data of a single input partition. Compare http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html#parallelism-model

Comment: And to clarify "Both topics will have GBs of data, so there is no chance that is going to fit in Streams App memory.": A key motivation to use RocksDB in Kafka Streams is to be able to manage state (joins are stateful operations) whose size is larger than available main memory (RAM/heap).  That's why you can do joins with GBs or even TBs of data.

Comment: Thanks Matthias and Michael. What is still not clear to be what machine are we talking about. Let's say I have Kafka nodes A, B and C and a Kafka Stream application running on X that does exactly what your example code shows. So will X have to hold that data from both topics locally in RocksDB, or does it just provide the joining mechanism and server X doesn't do much and all of the join work is put to Kafka Nodes A, B and C with RockDB on them holding all the processed data as well as Topic data?

Comment: All processing happens on the application node X (ie, RocksDB will be on X, and the join computation happens on X). The brokers (A,B,C) are not involved in the join (they don't even know that there is a Kafka Streams application -- to the broker, it looks like any other consumer). Btw: RocksDB doesn't need to hold "all" data: as both topics should be compacted topics RocksDB only needs to hold the latest key-value-pair for each key.

Comment: RocksDb is on the cluster side or application side?

Comment: RocksDB is client/application side.

Comment: So RocksDb is on application side if my application crashed then I will lost all state? Maybe standby replicas are required to keep state after crash ?

Comment: State is also backed up in a topic broker sides to guarantee fault-tolerance. If you crash and a task is moved to another instance, the state will be recreated from the topic. StandbyTasks don't provide fault-tolerance, but allow you to recover faster.

Comment: could you update link to the doc? seem to lead anywhere